Mean squared displacement of a free Brownian particle moving in harmonic potential
For a free Brownian particle moving under harmonic potential ($\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2$), the equation of motion can be written as,
$$m\ddot{x}=-m\omega^2 x-m\gamma\dot{x}+R(t)\;,$$
where, $\gamma$ is the friction coefficient and $R(t)$ is the random force.
The Mean Squared Displacement (MSD) for this model can be exactly calculated and turns out to be,
$$\big<\Delta x^2\big>=\frac{2k_BT_d}{m\omega^2}\big[1-\exp\big(-\frac{\gamma t}{2}\big)\{\cos(\bar\omega t)-\frac{\gamma}{2\bar \omega}\sin(\bar \omega t)\}\big]\;,$$
where, $\bar \omega=\sqrt{\omega^2 - (\gamma/2)^2}.$
See this paper for the expression.
It seems that this MSD is for only one dimensional motion. How will the MSD be modified for a two dimensional motion? That means, for a free Brownian particle moving under harmonic potential in say, $2$ dimensions in the $xy$ plane, will the MSD be,
$$\big<\Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2\big>=2\frac{2k_BT_d}{m\omega^2}\big[1-\exp\big(-\frac{\gamma t}{2}\big)\{\cos(\bar\omega t)-\frac{\gamma}{2\bar \omega}\sin(\bar \omega t)\}\big]\; ?$$
The above expression seems to be the answer, because for a two dimensional motion in $xy$ plane, the equations of motion for the particle along $x$- and $y$-directions,
\begin{align}
m\ddot{x}&=-m\omega^2 x-m\gamma\dot{x}+R(t)\;,\\
m\ddot{y}&=-m\omega^2 y-m\gamma\dot{y}+R(t)\;.
\end{align}
Am I correct?

You are close; the mean square displacement of a $n$D vector would be,
\begin{align}
MSD&=\langle\vert\mathbf{x}(t)-\mathbf{x}(0)\vert^2\rangle\\
&=\langle\{x(t)-x(0)\}^2+\{y(t)-y(0)\}^2+\cdots\rangle\\
&=\langle\{x(t)-x(0)\}^2\rangle+\langle\{y(t)-y(0)\}^2\rangle+\cdots\\
&=\langle\Delta x^2\rangle+\langle\Delta y^2\rangle+\cdots
\end{align}
where in the third line we have used the independence of the coordinates to separate their mean displacements.
Then if $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ follow the same stochastic distribution, you would obtain $MSD_{2D}=2\,MSD_{1D}$; extension to higher dimensions would show that $MSD_{nD}=n\,MSD_{1D}$.
